# Will manually setting the expire timestamp in the boost_cache table actually expire the cache for a node?

Tags: 6, database, caching

I am trying to get myself acquainted with Boost running on my Drupal 6 website. I know that boost has a boost_cache table where it stores the expires value for each node.

Now I want to know whether that if I set the value in the expire column manually to a preferred value, Boost will recognize it and expire the cached version of the node on the date in the timestamp and there **is no other table related to Boost caching where I should make the changes**.

Comment: Presumably you've tried it, did anything happen to suggest that manually setting the value _doesn't_ expire the cache straight away? Or are you worried about edge cases/other modules getting involved/etc?

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer to use

[boost_expire_node](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!boost!boost.module/function/boost_expire_node/6)

which will actively flush the node from boost static html cache

It could be scheduled, if needed ( e.g a [hook_cron_queue_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7) implementation worker callback ) or done as an immediate expiry